# Cannot use embedded custom fonts on WPF but works on winforms

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, fonts

I'm having troubles using a specific custom font on WPF.

I'm using two fonts, IndieFlower and HelveticaNeueLT Std Med Cn
However when attempting to add them to my XAML, IndieFlower works but HelveticaNeueLT Std Med Cn does not work.

My XAML for Indie Flower:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="The quick brown fox" FontSize="35" 
           FontFamily="../Resources/IndieFlower.ttf#Indie Flower"
       Margin="36,0,32.5,123" Height="51" Width="328.5" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2">
</TextBlock>
```

My XAML for Helvetica

```
<TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="The quick brown fox" FontSize="35" 
           FontFamily="../Resources/HelveticaNeueLTStd_MdCn.ttf#HelveticaNeueLT Std Med Cn"
       Margin="36,0,32.5,123" Height="51" Width="328.5" Grid.Row="4" Grid.RowSpan="2">
</TextBlock>
```

The top text is the Indie Flower and the bottom is suppose to be Helvetica
[image: The top text is the Indie Flower and the bottom is suppose to be Helvetica]

However the bottom is not Helvetica. [Here](http://font2s.com/fonts/50722/helvetica_neue_lt_std_67_medium_condensed.html) is the link to the Helvetica font.

I had to convert the font from OFT to TFF so it can be compatible with WinForms. I am using the PrivateFontCollection class for GDI (Which works fine)

- Both are Resources within my project and the "Build Action" is set to
  Resource.
- Indie Flower is displayed fine but not Helvetica.
- I can install the Helvetica font and view it on my character map without
  any issues.
- I can run the Helvetica via WinForms and display it using GDI DrawString.
- I double checked the File name AND the font name. 
  [image]

The only difference is that Helvetica font I manually converted from OTF to TFF. So I downloaded a different OTF file converted it to TTF and it works fine. So I'm really stuck to as why Helvetica doesn't work.

Comment: Have You tried it in size 67?

Comment: @ntohl Yeah I just tried it, doesn't work either.